# When copying Exchange Calendar to Sharepoint Calendar attendee information is lost

Tags: outlook

When I copy calendar items over from an Exchange Calendar (using Outlook 2010) to a SharePoint 2010 Calendar list, the attendees are lost. How can I copy over the attendees as well? The link to Exchange is via   the Internet (Web Outlook), rather than on the same network that SharePoint is on.

How can you invite attendees on a SharePoint Calendar so they are added to their calendar in the same way as if you were using Outlook (yours or a shared calendar)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sharepoint calendars don't have any attendee knowledge.  Calendars are just a listing of events so to speak.  You'd want to create a meeting workspace for that which are attendee aware.  This will give you a site with various components to help document the meeting.

Comment: There is an attendees column available that I have added to the Event content type, but even any entries in that aren't shown in Outlook.